# Command line zip everything within a directory, but do not include any directory as the root

Tags: macos, unix, zip, command-line-interface

I can't find the answer to this for the life of me. Because I am packaging a zip in a specific way for a build process, I don't want to include a folder at all in the resulting zip at the root. For example, if I have this file path:

```
MyFolder/
    A.png
    B.txt
    C.mp3
```

And I use either the command:

```
zip -r -X "MyFolder.zip" MyFolder/*
```

or

```
cd MyFolder; zip -r -X "../MyFolder.zip" *
```

I end up with a zip file that has the root element of MyFolder. What I want is for when I unzip it is to dump all of it right into the directory, like this:

```
A.png
B.txt
C.mp3
```

In other words, I don't want MyFolder or any other folder as the root. I read through the whole manual and have tried numerous options and a lot of Google searching, and zip seems to just *really* want to have a folder at the root.

Thanks!

Comment: Surprised that the second test doesn't do what you want. I just tested it here and as I would have expected, it does not include "MyFolder" in the paths.

Comment: Yeah, if I unzip it unzips a folder called "MyFolder" containing everything, it doesn't dump everything into that directory as desired. This is on Mac OS X.

Comment: When you zip, or when you run zipinfo on the resulting .zip, does it give you paths including `MyFolder`? I tried it on my Mac (OS X 10.9.3) and it worked as expected.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mix up the resulting zip files? Also remember that running zip on an existing archive adds more files rather than creating a new archive.

Comment: zipinfo looks correct! Sweet monkey balls, the problem was Mac OS X (opening the zip from the Finder using Archive Utility. Using unzip in the command line works as expected. Thanks for the sanity check!

Comment: I nearly tried it, but didn't, thinking it couldn't find the name of the folder if it wasn't there, but I suppose it uses the name of the zip file as the folder name?

Comment: Yeah, it looks that way.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It was Archive Utility's fault (a Mac OS X unzipper app). When I used the unzip command from the command line, it works great.

```
(cd MyFolder && zip -r -X "../MyFolder.zip" .)
```

Comment: I tweaked your solution so you don't have to actually leave the current directory by wrapping your code in `()` and switching the `;` to a `&&` e.g.


`(cd MyFolder && zip -r -X ../MyFolder.zip .)`

Answer (score 20):

Stumbled across this answer but didnt want to have to change in out of directories. I found the `-j` option useful which adds all files to the root of the zip. Note that its is **all files** so subdirectory structure will not be preserved.

So with this folder structure:

```
MyFolder
 - MyFile1
 - MySubFolder
   - MyFile2
```

And this command:

```
zip -rj MyFolder.zip MyFolder
```

You get this:

```
MyFolder.zip
 - MyFile1
 - MyFile2
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the easier way to make an ***encrypted zip file*** with the terminal app on mac (mac os) **just from the files of your folder**.

The command for the terminal

```
zip -j -e wishedname.zip yourfolder/*
```

That's it. Enjoy!

*

For more information to **zip command** in the terminal app

```
man zip
```

What **-j** and **-e** do?

```
-j
--junk-paths
Store  just  the  name  of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store directory names. By default, zip will store the full path (relative to the current directory).

-e
--encrypt
Encrypt  the contents of the zip archive using a password which is entered on the terminal in response to a prompt (this will not be echoed; if standard error is not a tty, zip will  exit with an error).  The password prompt is repeated to save the user from typing errors.
```

Answer (score -1):

Install zip

```
sudo apt install zip
```

use zip

```
zip -r foo.zip .
```

You can use the flags -0 (none) to -9 (best) to change compressionrate

Excluding files can be done via the -x flag. From the man-page:

```
-x files
--exclude files
          Explicitly exclude the specified files, as in:

                 zip -r foo foo -x \*.o

          which  will  include the contents of foo in foo.zip while excluding all the files that end in .o.  The backslash avoids the shell filename substitution, so that the name matching
          is performed by zip at all directory levels.

          Also possible:

                 zip -r foo foo -x@exclude.lst

          which will include the contents of foo in foo.zip while excluding all the files that match the patterns in the file exclude.lst.

          The long option forms of the above are

                 zip -r foo foo --exclude \*.o

          and

                 zip -r foo foo --exclude @exclude.lst

          Multiple patterns can be specified, as in:

                 zip -r foo foo -x \*.o \*.c

          If there is no space between -x and the pattern, just one value is assumed (no list):

                 zip -r foo foo -x\*.o

          See -i for more on include and exclude.
```